# Is it possible to define a differentiable manifold structure on a cone?

Tags: manifolds

A cone is a topologic manofold but can we define  a differentiable manifold structure on it?

Comment: What is a cone?

Comment: Z=radical(x^2+y^2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The projection $p$ from the cone onto the $x,y$-plane is a homeomorphism. So you can use $p$ to pull back the differential manifold structure on the $x,y$-plane and you get a differential manifold structure on the cone.

Comment: Is a curve $c$ on the cone smooth iff $p \circ c$ is smooth in $\Bbb R ^2$? If so, then this is weird: there are "V"-shaped curves on the cone that are "visually" not smooth (they have a pointed vertex at the tip of the cone), the projection of which is smooth. I can't understand this visual paradox.

Comment: @AlexM.: The cone can be given a smooth structure when considered as an abstract topological manifold, but that structure is not straightforwardly obtainable from its embedding in $\Bbb{R}^3$. (As you've noticed, it has "too many" smooth curves. Conversely, it has "too few" smooth functions; e.g., the restriction of $z$ to the cone is not a smooth function.)